# How to add different color of option value inside form-select?

Tags: html, select

I am trying to have the calendar name to be black , and only the spot ● should be in color(RED, BLUE, GREEN AND YELLOW).
Here is my code .

```
class="form-select form-select-lg"
aria-label=".form-select-lg example">
<option  v-for="calendar in edit.calendars"
    :value="calendar.calendar_name"> <i class="fas fa-circle" :style="{color:calendar.calendar_color}" ></i>
        <span>[[calendar.calendar_name]]</span>
</option>
</select>
```

I want a solution like this picture
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeMbP.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t, you can use other component like dropdown and using a list to do the circles, or you have to use some plugin like select2 and you will have the expected output

https://select2.org/